# Deployment of Beanstalk on Docker via Codepipeline is not complete

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am using the Codepipeline after configuring the Beanstalk On Docker environment.

But I am not completing the deployment phase.

My Dockerfile and buildspec.yml are:

What am I making a mistake?

### buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-northeast-2
    AWS_EB_DEPLOY_ENV: docker
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
      nodejs: 10
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo npm install
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build .
artifacts:
  files:
    - Dockerfile
```

### Dockerfile in repo root path

```
FROM node:12.16.3-alpine

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app

RUN npm install -g pm2
RUN npm install --production

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

Comment: Any errors? And why you install npm in buildspec?

Comment: Also does deploying manually using BS console work as expected?

Comment: @Marcin 
I think artifacts are probably the problem.

I removed artifacts from buildspec.yml. The reason is that I thought uploading a Dockerfile was meaningless. And I got the following error. "The action failed because either the artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found. Name of artifact bucket: codepipeline-ap-northeast-2-<number>. Verify that this bucket exists. If it exists, check the life cycle policy, then try releasing a change. "

Comment: CP passes artifacts between its stages (Source->Build->Deploy) using an S3 bucket. As the error message says, does it exsist, does it contain the artifacs? You can go and inspect what is there, unpack the artifacs, check if they are correct.

Comment: I have never configured separate artifacts.

Does this matter? I am not sure what artifacts should be defined in buildspec.yml.

Comment: How do you deploy your app manually in EB? Probably you have some zip file which contains the Docerfile and source code of your app? This zip file should be the artifact which results from CB and is picked up by CD for deployment in EB.

Comment: I used Codepipeline, so I checked that the code from github is passed as a zip file.

Comment: That's correct. CB will take the zip file, does what it has to do based on your buildspec.yaml, and then produce new zip file for CD to depoly. But do you really need the build step? Maybe your original zip file from GitHub does not need anything done on it for deployment?

Comment: Is it that you don't need all of buildspec.yml's build commands?

Codepipeline only need to pass zip file to beanstalk?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to do anything on the zip file from github (e.g. modify any .ebextensions, add some other config files, etc.). In that case your CP would be just: Source action from GitHub -> Deploy action to BS.